# Appended element does not move smoothly on mousemove?

Tags: jquery, append, mouseevent, onmousemove

I want to make a loading tip when you click on a button. Below is my attempt,

```
this.mouse_loader_click = function(){   

    /* CONFIG */        
    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 20;       

    $(".mouse-loader").click(function(e){

        /* append the popup */
        $(document.body).append("<p class='loading-tip'>Loading</p>");
        $(".loading-tip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");

        $(document.body).mousemove(function(e){
            $(".loading-tip")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
        });

        return false;

    });


};
```

But it works funny because the `loading element` - **".loading-tip"** does not move along with the mouse **smoothly**. It seems jerky all the time.

But it works fine and moves smoothly with the mouse if it is inside a box.

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x4KZ/) please.

What have I missed? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to only be because `document.body` isn't 100% of the height of the browser window.  Thus when you get below the bottom of the body it no longer is firing the `mousemove` event.

Add these two lines to your jsfiddle and try it again:

```
html { height:100%; }
body { height:100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try animating instead of setting static positions, to create smoother transitions.

```
$(document.body).mousemove(function(e){
    $(".loading-tip").stop().animate({
        top     : (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px",
        left    : (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px"
    }, 100); // 100 is the desired time in milliseconds from point A to point B, play with it if it's not smooth enough for you :)
});
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. It still have the same problem. but I think it is `because document.body isn't 100% of the height of the browser window.` as Jason pointed out.